# controlling the application flow in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an application that when accessed its the main.php controller, which spits out the main_view.php view.  Now I was wondering what is the right way to go from this view to another controller to generate the next view.  The CI tutorials just talk about going from controller to view not the other way around.  I have a form that I need to submit on main_view.php and then generate the next view from a database based on that info.

thnks!

Answer (score 0):

You target controllers and functions in the url like this `yoursite.com/controller_name/function_name`. so the form on `main_view.php` can link to any controller/function you want, ie `yoursite.com/form_controller/form_processing_function`

Answer (score 0):

Use `site_url` to ensure portability of your application:

```
echo site_url("controller/method");
```

See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Read this chapter in the user guide:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html